# SSRS Report Dataset not throwing query time out exception

Tags: sql, timeout, dataset, ssrs-2008

I am trying to set the query time out for **dataset** of the report to a small value and want to **replicate query  timeout issue**.

I have set query time for **Dataset** to **20** sec and ran the report. The report has ran for 140 sec and does not throw any exception.

Why is this happening ? Can any one please suggest whats going wrong here .

Comment: There are several places to set the timeout. Are you doing this in Report Builder, SSDT, report manager, SharePoint...?

Comment: I have set it at the report level (embedded dataset )

Comment: Do you have any complex grouping or calculations on the report that could cause it to take a long time to render after the dataset query is done?